# Recent posts with different class name for each post and a scrollbar?

Tags: widgets, recent-posts

So far i found a widget ("**Ultimate Posts Widget**") with different class name for each post but it has no scroll bar..

any other widget suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Vertical Scroll Recent Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/vertical-scroll-recent-post/) plugin. It enables you to scroll the recent posts vertically. You can specify the number of posts to scroll. You can also choose the category and the order. .